# Discord.js cancellation of modal cause crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I use the following method to wait for the modal reply after executing the slash command.

```js
        await interaction.showModal(submissionValidateModal);

        const modalReply = await interaction.awaitModalSubmit({
            time: 60000,
            filter: i => i.user.id === interaction.user.id,
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
            return null;
        })

        // Handling Stuff

        modalReply.reply({ embeds: [requestedSentEmbed], ephemeral: true });
```

However, if the user execute the command, and the bot will be waiting for the modal submit event. The await would not be cancelled even if the user click cancel in this situation. When the user quickly execute the command again, and submit with the modal, it will eventually causing the error: `Interaction has already been acknowledged`. I believe this happens because there is more than 1 collector waiting for the modal submit, when the modal is submitted, it will cause the bot attempting to reply a more than once.

Anyone have clues on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of [DJS Documentation](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.11.0/class/ChatInputCommandInteraction?scrollTo=awaitModalSubmit)

You need the `.then` method. Since awaitModalSubmit already acknowledges the command

```js
// Collect a modal submit interaction
const filter = (interaction) => interaction.customId === 'modal';
interaction.awaitModalSubmit({ filter, time: 15_000 })
  .then(interaction => console.log(`${interaction.customId} was submitted!`))
  .catch(console.error);
```